# Magento - Add to cart showing up wierdly

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, block

http://sandbox.jinoh.dk/magento/index.php/produkter

This is the link where I develop a Magento webshop for a client. I have some problems. If you search Webshop, the Add to cart buttons will appear just fine but on the Show All Products page - created with this block code {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} - the Add to Cart button is showing up wierdly. I can't seem to find the problem, which annoys me :(

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `position:absolute` for your `.products-grid .actions` class. At your search page you have separate  list for each row while at your CMS page you have one list for all rows so all buttons are positioned relatively to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Thank you! It was extremely helpful. I had to layout a bit different too, but your tip was the main thing that made me able to continue!